# How can I align the text that didn't fit the first line to right in CSS, like they do in poetry?

Tags: html, css

I'm adding some poetry to my website. The problem is, when the screen size gets smaller, lines of the poem break. I want to show the part of the line that comes after the line break like they do in poetry books, when the verse doesn't fit the page width. Here's an example:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the
                           lazy dog
```

The first line is aligned to left, the second however, is aligned to right. (This will only happen in small screens, of course.)

Is there any way to do this that is repeatable? This is not a one-time thing; I'm trying to create a standard with classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `text-align-last`

```css
.box {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  resize:horizontal;
  overflow:auto;
}
.box * {
  /*text-align:justify; uncomment this to see the justify effect, not bad too */
  text-align-last: right;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div><br>
  <div>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This aligns the entire document right if there are no wide breaking lines.

Comment: This is what I was asking for, thank you. It works great.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [CSS pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) for selecting the first line of text that you could use here:

`::first-line`

**Update:** Despite the selector being supported in all major browsers it appears that several browsers don't allow `text-align` to be applied to this selector. So this is not a reliable cross-browser solution (yet?), I will leave it here in case it's useful to anyone or becomes valid in the future.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#wrapper span {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
#wrapper span::first-line {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
  <span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</span>
  <span>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.</span>
</div>
```

This does assume you will have at most 1 line of overflow (all overflowing lines will be right aligned) but at that point it will look a little strange no matter the styling.

Comment: This is a great answer. I am genuinely (and surprisingly) happy to see this answer. I would however add a `padding-right:1rem` to the standard span as in text books and the example the OP posted, the overflow line is offset a little from the end of the original line. (This could also be done with negative margin, etc.)

Comment: Hmm - quick browser test on Mac: This works in Chrome and Opera, but doesn't in Firefox and Safari...

Comment: @Johannes Damn, you're right, it seems like despite `::first-line` being supported everywhere, the rules you can apply to it vary by browser.

Comment: It works for me on Firefox 82 (on linux, though, not on Mac).

Comment: Does not work for me on Firefox 82.0.2 Linux(XFCE, Manjaro)